# FBJS-BRIDGE , Stopped working since yesterday?

Tags: flash, facebook, fbjs

I have a facebook app, which works with fbjs/flash/python. From yesterday I have been getting the following security error.

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'http://apps.facebook.com/feline-frenzy/bridgetest/' tried to access incompatible context 'http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z71HX/hash/4h1ls3l8.swf'
```

While the same code was working fine the other day. Upon inspection when the fbjs-bridge wants to send something to flash. The following is my code.

**MY FBML :**

```
<fb:fbjs_bridge/>
<div id="swfContainer"></div>
<script>
       var swf = document.createElement('fb:swf');
       swf.setId('my_swf_id');
       swf.setWidth('630');
       swf.setHeight('520');
       swf.setSWFSrc('http://media.varheroes.com/flash/bridge.swf'); 
       document.getElementById('swfContainer').appendChild(swf);
       document.getElementById('my_swf_id').callSWF('asMethod', 'one', 'two');
 </script>
 <script>
 <!--
      function flashtest(){
    document.getElementById('my_swf_id').callSWF('asMethod','fahim','akhter');
      }

  -->
  </script>

  <div id="crap">
        <a href="#" onclick="flashtest();">FLASH TEST</a><br/>
  </div>
```

**MY ACTIONSCRIPT CODE:**

```
  var connection:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
   var connectionName:String =  LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.fb_fbjs_connection;

connection.allowDomain("apps.facebook.com", "apps.*.facebook.com");
    connection.client = {
        asMethod: function(paramOne:String, paramTwo:String) {
        // do something in the SWF
        var test:String = "DATA RECIEVED FROM JAVASCRIPT : "+paramOne+" "+paramTwo;
        callSetText("DATA RECIEVED FROM JAVASCRIPT");
    }
};
connection.connect(connectionName);
```

The error started happening yesterday like I said first it was working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that is affecting different applications and there is a bug already reported:

http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8562

So far I haven't personally found an alternative to this issue and it seems like all we can do is wait for them to make an update that will fix the issue.